# Why is Django UUIDField with editable=False is editable?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I want to make the UUID field not editable in Django, i am using the uuid as the  names of static files which loses its integrity if the corresponding UUID is changed. I was trying to make UUID readonly (on shell, not concerned about forms and admin) so that nothing should never change the uuid of a model once defined.

```
class Car(models.Model):
    uuid = muuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
```

so when i try to change the uuid in shell

```
>>> x = Car.objects.first()
>>> x.uuid
    UUID('acd963cf-aa2f-4f44-988d-87091d492766')
>>> x.uuid = uuid.uuid4
>>> x.save()
>>> x.uuid
    UUID('1155ce6d-d783-4dc8-a970-a004dc63f3d8')
```

Django version is 2.1.7, database is PostgreSQL 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could overwrite the save method -- lookup the value in the DB and set the values to be the same before saving, if they are different.

```
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.pk:
            obj = Car.objects.values('uuid').get(pk=self.pk)
            if obj.get('uuid') != self.uuid:
                self.uuid = obj.get('uuid')
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 5):

Check the docs for [editable field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#editable).

> If False, the field will not be displayed in the admin or any other
> ModelForm. They are also skipped during model validation. Default is
> True.

It does not mean that can't be changed from the shell.